# Truncating Strings from a column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column which has values divided by colon ":".
For example DT:CSDF , SFT:TAHS etc...

I just need to take the right side i.e. CSDF,TAHS etc

How do I do it in the select clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you will never have dots, you can use this

```
PARSENAME(REPLACE(ColumnName,':','.'),1)
```

example

```
DECLARE @v VARCHAR(100) = 'DT:CSDF'


SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(@v,':','.'),1)
```

otherwise use PATINDEX and RIGHT

```
SELECT RIGHT(ColumnName,LEN(ColumnName) -PATINDEX('%:%',ColumnName))
```

Example

```
DECLARE @v VARCHAR(100) = 'DT:CSDF'


SELECT RIGHT(@v,LEN(@v) -PATINDEX('%:%',@v))
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(YourField, 
                 CHARINDEX(':', YourField) + 1, 
                 LEN(YourField)
                 ) AS YourNewField
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
SUBSTR( INSTR( mycol, ':' ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(fieldname, CHARINDEX(':', fieldname) + 1, LEN(fieldname)) 
FROM ...
```

More t-sql string functions you can find here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms181984(v=sql.90).aspx